# Marshall entity without any relationship

Tags: java, xml, jpa

Currently, I have a class using JPA to connect to database that could look like this one.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Pet> pets;

    @OneToOne
    private House house;
}
```

and I am using `javax.ws.rs` annotations to create xml webservices like this one

```
@GET
@Path("/load")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response loadByPetId(@QueryParam("petId") int petId) {
    return Response.ok(personBean.loadByPetId(petId)).build();
}
```

(I am using eclipselink)

```
@Stateless
public class PersonBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "...")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public PersonBean() {
        super(Person.class);
    }

    public List<Person> loadByPetId(int petId) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByPetId", Person.class).setParameter("petId", petId).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

that returns an xml that contains each attributes **and relationships** from the given `Person` such as

```
<Person>
    <name>toto</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <Pets>
        <Pet>
            ...
        </Pet>
        <Pet>
            ...
        </Pet>
        ...
    </Pets>
    <House>
        ...
    </House>
</Person>
```

I want to be able to create an other webservice that load **only the attributes of the given `Person` without relationships** such as

```
<Person>
    <name>toto</name>
    <age>18</age>
</Person>
```

But, as I am using `Pets` to load the correct `Person`, the `Pets` list is loaded and i do not know how to *"unload it"* to prevent it to be in my xml.

Comment: Use a DTO (Data Transfer Object, custom object, not persisted, only exposing what is relevant for the current request) or depending on the use case and the framework used to produce the xml, look at the corresponding annotation (@JsonIgnore with json and jackson)

Comment: What kind of JPA implementation are you using, could you add the class of `personBean` ?

Comment: @Arnaud I use eclipselink, I added PersonBean class.